# select distinct and where in so slow

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table1
row_id      row_one     row_two
1           1           5
2           1           5
3           2           5
4           2           5
5           2           6

table2
row2_id     row2_one    row2_two
1           1           somevalue
2           2           somevalue2

"select distinct row_one from table1 where row_two=5"
```

result

```
row_one
1
2
```

after that i want select

```
select * from table2 where row2_one=1
select * from table2 where row2_one=2
```

i want select with one query.
i am trying this query

```
 select * from table2 where row2_one in (select distinct row_one from table1 where  
          row_two where row_two=5)
```

but it took 8s
`Showing rows 0 - 14 ( 15 total, Query took 8.3255 sec)`

why is it so slow. i want select faster.
please help me!

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: Your SQL Statement has 2 where clauses. This does not look correct

Comment: can you revise your question? It looks very confusing

Comment: MySQL!
How correct?
Sorry my english bad

Comment: @user52878 - What indexes do you have on the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `DISTINCT` in there. You can just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE row2_one IN (SELECT row_one FROM table1 WHERE row_two=5)
```

And using `EXISTS` might be faster:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 A
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE row_two=5 AND row_one = A.row2_one)
```

Comment: EXISTS Showing rows 0 - 14 ( 15 total, Query took 7.0873 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to the that was said bellow - use [GROUP BY](http://readvitamin.com/2007/10/18/using-%E2%80%9Cgroup-by%E2%80%9D-instead-of-%E2%80%9Cdistinct%E2%80%9D-clause/) or [EXISTS](http://www.zimbio.com/member/vijaya_krishna_birju/articles/M0M0UJrtZab/Use+EXISTS+instead+DISTINCT+improve+Query) instead of DISTINCT it can really improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is your query:

```
select *
from table2 where row2_one in (select distinct row_one from table1 where row_two=5)
```

Then this is well-formed.  One thing, you don't need the distinct in the subquery.

If you add an index to the table1 on the column row_two, you should get better performance.  An index on row2_one in table2 would also speed it up.

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 14 ( 15 total, Query took 8.6982 sec) for don't have distinct

Comment: table1 have 45460 rows and table 2 have 1150 rows

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Those are really not large numbers

Comment: Lamak, you are correct.  That's what a meant to write.  How come I can sometimes edit my comments and at other times not.

Comment: Those are not large numbers. Could the types of the columns be different in the two tables? How are row_one and row_two declared in each table? A difference in data types can cause very suboptimal query execution plans

Comment: [About (un)editable comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select distinct table2.* 
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.row_two =5 and t1.row2_one = t2.row2_one
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I hope you mean abt mistake regarding wrong col name (t1.table1) which I have corrected